# Zune 4.00 software volume ineffective; follows Windows sound volume

Tags: zune

For some reason, I do not know if it happened when i upgraded to Zune 4.00 on Windows, or after i migrated the OS onto a new motherboard (thus new onboard audio chipset) yesterday, but I just noticed the volume bar is completely not working. Yes i do not use the Zune program on Windows that often.

The volume bar can be adjusted or even muted but the Zune program continues to play the audio clips/podcasts based on the main Windows volume setting.

As far as i have tested, Winamp, Windows Media Player, other software with independent volume controls work normally. Only Zune appears to have this problem.

Anybody know how Zune program directs sound to Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, through some apparent massive abuse of the network adapter I put Windows/Outlook through (not spam), it STOP Error blue-screened on me, forcing me to restart the computer.

On fresh system boot, Zune's volume bar works now. :-/